# Area mapped over list of 2 polygons crashes kernel depending on order

Tags: kernel, crash

I have a list of 2 `Polygon` objects (see below for the list `polys` and a visualization). They are all seem valid. Still, when I try to map `Area` over this list (after a fresh kernel restart), it crashes the kernel. Surprisingly, when mapping over the reversed list (after a fresh kernel restart) it works. For each individual `Polygon` in the list, `Area` works as expected.

This bug has kept me busy for a full day already, finally pinpointing it to this MWE.

- What is going on here?
- How can this be avoided?
- What is a 'safe' order of the polygons in a list, in order to map `Area` over it?

My setup: Macbook Pro, 32 GB RAM, macOS 10.14.6, Mathematica 13.0.

What doesn't work for me (after a fresh kernel start; though, doing this after trying what does work, it also works; maybe a caching issue?):

```
Map[Area, polys]
```

The above call silently crashes my kernel (no error message whatsoever).

The following do work (try each after restarting the kernel, e.g. using `Quit[]`):

```
Area@polys[[1]]
Area@polys[[2]]
Map[Area, Reverse@polys]
```

N.B. Polygon 1 has two (almost) collinear edges. In other cases this has never been an issue.  Besides, the evaluation of the individual areas is not the issue.  The crash is triggered by the order of evaluation.

A visualization of the 2 polygons (they come from a much longer list):

[image: 2 polygons]

Here is the list of polygons:

```
polys = {Polygon[{{-12., 20.784609690826528`}, {-16., 
    13.856406460551018`}, {0., 0.}, {-6., 10.392304845413264`}}], 
   Polygon[{{48., 20.784609690826528`}, {42., 31.17691453623979}, {
    36., 20.784609690826528`}}]};
```

Comment: Work fine in 13.0.1. `{62.3538, 83.1384}` `{83.1384, 62.3538}`

Comment: So, is this a known bug?

Comment: Works in Mma 13.0.1 on Win 10

Comment: Works on a MacBookPro, 32GB RAM, macOS 12.2.1, Mathematica 13.0.0 and 13.0.1

Comment: Problem persists after updating to Mma 13.0.1. Strange and annoying.

Comment: After further experimentation, on my system (MacBookPro, 32GB RAM, macOS 12.2.1, MMA 13.0.1), it depends on the order of the evaluations not just the order of the polygons. Evaluating `Map[Area, Reverse@polys]` first then `Map[Area, polys]` works fine. However, evaluating `Map[Area, Reverse@polys]` after `Map[Area, polys]` (even if `Map[Area, Reverse@polys]` has already been successfully evaluated) crashes the kernel. Oddly, `Area /@ (polys = RandomPolygon[3, 10])` and `Area /@ Reverse[polys]` work irrespective of order. Recommend that you report this to Wolfram Tech Support.

Comment: Silently crashes on v12.2.0 Win7-x64 on `Map[Area, polys]`.

Comment: No crash experienced on v12.1.1.0 Linux after evaluating them several times.

Comment: I reported it to Wolfram Tech Support.